# API Keys on .travis.yml and using it in code

Tags: python-2.7, github, travis-ci

I have an application I am currently working on for which I am integrating Travis CI. I am running into the problem of API keys being accessed by Travis. Given below is my current setup (without Travis):

I have a `config.py` (and is git ignored) that has API keys for all my interfacing applications. I use `ConfigParser` to read this file and get the required keys.

Travis asks me to look at environment variables as an option to encrypt the keys and add them to `.travis.yml`. How would Travis know or what needs to be done in order to make travis know that a particular key belongs to a specific interfacing application. Does there need to be changes to the code?

Answer (score 0):

You would read these important variables into your application as system variables.

However, this will only work for builds that are run against master. These environment variables aren't available for builds that are run as part of pull requests.